# Coloring a grayscale sprite with HSV

Tags: android, colors, sprite, andengine, hsv

I am using AndEngine for a live wallpaper project, though I imagine my problem should be universal to Android or even Java entirely.  Until recently I was using SVG's for my images due to the scaling benefits, however because of the graphical limitations of vector art I decided to switch to PNG, and I can't seem to figure out how to get the HSV colorization I had before to apply to the new sprites properly.

At the moment I am basically just shoving some HSV values at the sprite, and it does technically work, but not properly.  I don't seem to have any real control over the saturation or value/brightness at all like I did before, there only seems to be two levels to them, as if they were being set to 0.0 or 1.0 instantly, though the color itself is very dark and obviously not at full value/brightness and saturation either way.

I don't see any real difference between what I am doing and what the setup I had for the SVG images was, so I am at a bit of a loss.  Presumably somewhere in the depths of AndEngine there was something else being done to make it all work properly, and I just don't know what it is to work it in now.  The relevant code that I am using, more or less, is :

```
        float[] temphsv = new float[3];
        int colorAfter = 0;

        Sprite tempSprite = new Sprite(x, y, 400, 600, mSprite);
        temphsv[0] = 120;
        temphsv[1] = 1.0f;
        temphsv[2] = 1.0f;
        colorAfter = Color.HSVToColor(temphsv);
        tempSprite.setColor(Color.red(colorAfter), Color.green(colorAfter), Color.blue(colorAfter));
```

Technically the way that code is right now the image should be just pure bright green, but instead it is instead a rather dark green and still retaining its shading.  I imagine this is something trivial since it worked fine with the SVG images, so any tip on what I'm missing would be great.

Comment: That's weird. When I try that code, it sets it to pure bright green as expected. Can you post a self-contained example of this?

Comment: Well, it's a little weird posting a running example as it depends on AndEngine.  As a test I opened up a simple sprite example from the AndEngine examples and did the above to the sprite, and it had the same effect there as in my own app, so I figure it is something to do with the way AndEngine handles these sprites now.  At the same time, I took a look at the code behind the coloring I was using while I had SVG graphics and I don't see anything special being done, yet it worked fine.